# Can I automatically generate the join_table when creating one model in a HABTM relationship at the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one model `User` and will be creating another one `Category`.

Both will have a HABTM relationship between both.

I have not created the `Category` model yet.

But, when I am generating it at the command line, can I also generate the join table?

If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can find, there is no way to generate the join table for a HABTM association at the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly generate the junction table, use `has_many :categories, through: :junction` and `has_many :users, through: :junction` in your models. Then explicitly generate a model Junction that contains a user_id and category_id, and that belongs_to user and belongs_to category. The user and category will also need to have has_many :junctions.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I am asking. What I want to know is if there is a rails command that I can run that will generate the other model - along with my join_table.